# MS Access query with pattern

Tags: ms-access, numbers

I am trying to implement in MS Access following query filter. I am trying do not show the numbers from my table which contains following pattern:

"NNNNNN_NNNN_NNN" AND "NNNNNN_NNNN_NNN-S/Z"

If I have in my database a number "123456_123_123" or "12345_1234_12" I cannot see them. So my filter pattern doesn't work correctly. Is there possibility to work in Access Query with underline symbols? How can I create correct pattern?

Thank you for any tip!

Answer (score 0):

Use the operator LIKE:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE ([columnname] NOT LIKE '######_####_###')
  AND ([columnname] NOT LIKE '######_####_###-S/Z')
```

The wildcard `'#'` represents a single digit.